# Why won't my websites Logo resize appropriately?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

**My desktop version of my website is perfect, and runs exactly how it should, however, on mobile. I've been having Issues**

### Issue 1

When I uploaded the files to the hosting server, the logo was enormous, and threw everything off balance

[Image was throwing everything off balance i.e. Huge Navbar, menu button not aligned to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJK8w.jpg)

I then resolved this issue with the following Code in my CSS

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 670px) {
  .site-branding img {
  max-width:320px;
  max-height:56px;
}
  .main-header {height:80px;}
}

  @media only screen and (min-width: 670px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .site-branding img {
    max-width:640px;
    max-height:118px;     
}
    .main-header {height:140px;}
}
```

### Issue 2

After implementing this, the Navbar shrunk, but so did the logo, and changing the values in my CSS did not change the logo size to an appropriate one. It just stayed the same size

[Issue 2 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOZVN.jpg)

### Issue 3

This change also affected my Products page, by extending the navbar length on the mobile version, extending the width of the navbar, while keeping all of the other content to it's original alignment

[Issue 3 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne6Ns.jpg)

### Conclusion

I'd like to know how to keep the logo and the menu bar aligned on the same line, while increasing the size of the logo for the mobile version of the site.

I also do not know what is causing the issue on the products page, and I have no idea how to resolve that issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Please check Below code I replace Some Html also I added a comment

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
                    <!-- <div class="site-branding" img src="img/Logo.png" > --> <!-- This is not a right way to put HTML -->
                    <div class="site-branding"> <!-- I Removed img src="img/Logo.png" -->
                        <img src="https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/mini-logo.png" style="width:100%; height: auto;" />  <!-- Here I changed width 100%; and Height auto -->
                    </div>
                </a>
```

And also add this css and You can change max-width as per your logo size

```
#mainNav .navbar-brand {
    max-width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping,
This didn't work. 

All it did was throw off the alignment even more.

Does this sound right or have i entered it incorrectly or in the wrong place ?

Comment: can you please put your code on live so I can check

Comment: How do i put it on live ?

Comment: Use This https://jsfiddle.net/ It's help you tu put live code so I can check and give you a proper solution

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ar8t2we1/

Please let me know if that link doesn't work

Comment: yes it's working but I can't see logo because image path not found

Comment: Should I upload the images to imgur and link them ?

Comment: you can use live link of images

Comment: because Your main issue with logo size so logo is required

Comment: Please tell me how,
Never used this before

Comment: it's wait I'll update you soon I'm using my own logo and complete your solution ASAP

Comment: Please check I renew my answer

Comment: This made the logo thin and blurry, also the logo is now much smaller on desktop site.
If I edit the width in the css, it makes it longer, but not taller. So it stays blurry

Comment: remove your media Query css and check again

Comment: The logo is now very small on the desktop website. It also looks very stretched out on my phone, but normal on someone elses phone.

Should i remove ALL media queries ?

Comment: Im not sure what else to do

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add `display:flex` to common parent

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

[image]

Comment: Thank you
But this didn't work,

All it did was move the menu button farther to the left